# Python. Compare and merge lists of dictionaries(diversed) by similar items

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists, defaultdict, deep-diff

I have two lists of dictionaries(lod). I want to compare and merge them if they have similar items(by keys `'id'` and `'size'`), and if not set some default value(0) with certain key(`'count'`) to the first lod.

```
lod1 = [{'id':1, 'size':1, 'colour':'a'}, {'id':1, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab'}, {'id':2, 'size':1, 'colour':'ab'}, {'id':2, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab'}]
lod2 = [{'id':1, 'size':1, 'count':1}, {'id':1, 'size':2, 'count':2}, {'id':2, 'size':1, 'count':3}]
```

Output:

```
merged = [{'id':1, 'size':1, 'colour':'a', 'count': 1}, {'id':1, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab', 'count': 2},  {'id':2, 'size':1, 'colour':'ab', 'count':3}, {'id':2, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab', 'count': 0}]
```

I draw your attention to `{'id':2 , 'size':2, 'colour':'ab', 'count': 0}`

There are a lot of similar questions and solutions about comparing and merging lods, but not the same. I know the way to do that but it looks too bulky, clumsy and inelegant.

My solution:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    lod1_pairs = [(i['id'], i['size']) for i in l1]
    lod2_pairs = [(i['id'], i['size']) for i in l2]
    mismatched = [pair for pair in lod1_pairs if pair not in lod2_pairs] 
    # we get list of unique pairs of lod1 to set default value to 'count' key.
    
    merged = []
    for i in lod1:
        if (i['id'], i['size']) in mismatched:
            #immediately cut off and evaluate 'count' key for the mismatched keys
            temp_dict = i| {'count': 0} 
            merged.append(temp_dict)
        else:
            for j in lod2:
                    #straightly compare key values
                    if i['id'] == j['id'] and i['size'] == j['size']:
                        temp_dict = i | j #merge dicts
                        merged.append(temp_dict)
    return merged


lod1 = [{'id':1, 'size':1, 'colour':'a'}, {'id':1 , 'size':2, 'colour':'ab'}, {'id':2, 'size':1, 'colour':'ab'}, {'id':2, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab'}]
lod2 = [{'id':1, 'size':1, 'count':1}, {'id':1, 'size':2, 'count':2}, {'id':2, 'size':1, 'count':3}]
merged = merge(lod1,lod2)
```

I had an experience with defaultdict, and reviewed a DeepDiff lib, but didn't understand how i can use them here.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more? Why in the result in `{'id':2, 'size':1, 'colour':'ab'}` is missing the `count` for example?

Comment: @AndrejKesely sorry, that's typo, fixed it.
In other words, if you have the dict with similar 'id' and 'size' values in both lists, like
`{'id':1, 'size':1, 'colour':'a'}` and `{'id':1, 'size':1, 'count':1}` you merge it to `{'id':1, 'size':1, 'colour':'a', count':1}` and add it to new list. If you have the unique pair of `'id'` and `'size'` in `lod1`, you update corresponding dict with `{'count':0}` and append it to same new list, like `{'id':2, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab'}` --> `{'id':2, 'size':2, 'colour':'ab', 'count':0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
out = {(d["id"], d["size"]): {**d, "count": 0} for d in lod1}
for d in lod2:
    t = d["id"], d["size"]
    if t in out:
        out[t]["count"] = d["count"]
    else:
        out[t] = d

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "size": 1, "colour": "a", "count": 1},
    {"id": 1, "size": 2, "colour": "ab", "count": 2},
    {"id": 2, "size": 1, "colour": "ab", "count": 3},
    {"id": 2, "size": 2, "colour": "ab", "count": 0},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different version without using if.. else:

```
def merge(lod1, lod2):
    dod2 = {(dct['id'], dct['size']): dct['count'] for dct in lod2}
    merged = []
    for entry in lod1:
        merged.append(entry)
        merged[-1]['count'] = dod2.get((entry['id'], entry['size']), 0)
    
    return merged

merge(lod1, lod2)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'size': 1, 'colour': 'a', 'count': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'size': 2, 'colour': 'ab', 'count': 2},
 {'id': 2, 'size': 1, 'colour': 'ab', 'count': 3},
 {'id': 2, 'size': 2, 'colour': 'ab', 'count': 0}]
```

Comment: Спасибо, Мария!

Comment: Рада помочь! :)